# Conditional Statements in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm building a simple app in swift that calculates the area of a space. I'm having an issue with the Conditional Statement that will return a message if the user does not enter a width or a height in the text box.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  areaCalculator
//
//  
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Dandre Ealy. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var widthTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightTxt: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var area: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        var width = widthTxt.text.toInt()
        var height = heightTxt.text.toInt()

        var areaPressed = width! * height!

        if ((width) && (height) != nil){
            area.text = "The area is \(areaPressed)"
        } else {
            area.text = "Enter the width and the height"
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue are you having? It's not clear from your question

Comment: I am getting an error with the && logic operator it says "Optional type '$T6' cannot be used as a boolean;test for '!=nil' instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is incorrect:

```
if ((width) && (height) != nil)
```

you have to explicitly check for not nil individually:

```
if width != nil && height != nil
```

There's another error though, which generates a runtime exception:

```
var areaPressed = width! * height!
```

if either `width` or `height` is nil. You should move that in the `if` body:

```
if width != nil && height != nil {
    var areaPressed = width! * height!
    area.text = "The area is \(areaPressed)"
} else {
    area.text = "Enter the width and the height"
}
```

The reason is that the forced unwrapping operator `!` requires that the optional variable it is applied to contains a non-nil value - unwrapping a nil results in a runtime exception.

Comment: @Swifter where is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (width != nil) && (height != nil){
    var areaPressed = width! * height!
    area.text = "The area is \(areaPressed)"         
} else {
    area.text = "Enter the width and the height"
}
```

or

```
if (width == nil) || (height == nil){
    area.text = "Enter the width and the height"        
} else {
    var areaPressed = width! * height!
    area.text = "The area is \(areaPressed)"
}
```

Comment: After I put your code in, my app crashes. I get this message in the console
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare and implement your own custom operators in addition to the standard operators provided by Swift.
it is more convenient code using Custom Operators

for exemple!!

```
prefix operator ! {}
prefix func ! (a: Int) -> Bool {
    return a != 0
}

if !width && !height {
  var areaPressed = width! * height!
    area.text = "The area is \(areaPressed)"
} else {
    area.text = "Enter the width and the height"
}
```